# String-ref in Racket -- What does #\ mean?

Tags: arrays, string, lisp, racket

In Racket, there is a built-in function called "string-ref", see the documentation [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=string-ref#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-ref%29%29).

I get the general concept of this function. However, I do not understand part of its output.

See this example:

```
>> (string-ref "Apple" 0)    

#\A
```

Ok, so "A" is the first character of "Apple". But why does the output present this characters "#\" before the letter A? How should I interpret this?

I did not see anything about that on the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this page:

https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html

and look in the "Delimiters and Dispatch" section, where it says:

```
#\  starts a character
```